# How to disable button after click for 5 minutes in Android

Tags: android

I'm new to android.I'm creating an app in which i have to disable the button after it is clicked, and enable it again after 5 minutes. Count down timer should continue even after app is closed. any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try using Handler

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK will Handler work if app is closed?

Comment: No, Handler will stop when app closed

Comment: You can create a service which will notify the listening components

Comment: I would suggest you to use services, and add the state in SharedPreference when the button is clicked and startService which should automatically change the value of SharedPreference and you button should be enabled again

Comment: Have you tried something to disabled the button for 5minutes ? Not talking about the seconds problem (persistance after shutdown). What happen after the 5minutes ? Same question when the app is closed

Comment: The easiest way is using sharedPreferences.. comparing time click with current time when user load the activity or you can regularly run a Handler for every 10 seconds. (**the handle only run in current activity only**)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can store time in shared preference by following code.

```
 SharedPreferences  settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 1);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putString("click_time", your_time);
```

Whenever need to compare, just compare your current time with the time stored in preference. Check if difference between time is less than 5 min or not.

TO get time from prefernce:

```
   SharedPreferences  settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 1);
   String storedTime=settings.getString("clic_time", "");
```

Get difference in minute:

```
   Date current, Date previous;
   long diff = current.getTime() - previous.getTime();
   long minutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
```

To show timer, when app comes from background, you can get time from preference and start timer by using difference between 2 times.

Comment: I was to lazy to write this, I would use the same solution. Just storing the time when to enabled the button again. Using a simple Timer and rebuilding it `onCreate` to end on the saved timed. No need to use Service on anything.

Comment: after putting value in shared preference, you should commit it. .editor.commit();

Answer (score 0):

```
private long mLastClickTime = 0;

public static final long MAX_CLICK_INTERVAL = 1000; // here you can pass the time interval you want the user to wait for the next click

// and paste the below code on button click 

if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < MAX_CLICK_INTERVAL) {
            return;
}
mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try Handler**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        // this will disable your button
        yourButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
};


yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // wait for 5 minutes
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5*60*1000);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Handler will work on main thread so that is not good way to solved this.